# transfer TRC20 asset from a 'noncontract' TRX wallet to another by API

Tags: api, tron, trx

I need to transfer TRC20 token from [this](https://nile.tronscan.org/#/address/TRYQ8gSqk8BY6kqJ868UCnDqPC7LtAgaaA) TRX  wallet to another by API.

Since it is doesn't have TRC20 smartcontract created, I can't trigger `triggersmartcontract`. Is there a way how can I automatically initiate a transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution
This TriggerSmartContract API with the transfer() method in USDT contract, this will create the transaction, then you'll need to sign and broadcast it.
https://developers.tron.network/reference/triggersmartcontract

and here is code example using [`IEXBase`](https://github.com/iexbase/tron-api) library

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$provider_url = 'https://nile.trongrid.io';

use IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron;


try {
    $fullNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider($provider_url);
    $solidityNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider($provider_url);
    $eventServer = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider($provider_url);
} catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


try {
    $tron = new Tron($fullNode, $solidityNode, $eventServer);
    $tron->setPrivateKey(private_key_here);
    $contract = $tron->contract('TXLAQ63Xg1NAzckPwKHvzw7CSEmLMEqcdj');  // Tether USDT https://tronscan.org/#/token20/TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t

    echo  $contract->transfer('TRYQ8gSqk8BY6kqJ868UCnDqPC7LtAgaaA', '5000', 'TXKXYoNvAjHBG4vd4EJjAXuVnozrt47tnd');


} catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```